# How to get the size of imageView that is set to match_parent?

Tags: android, imageview

So I have an imageView inside a listview (loaded by a Loader) and the width is set to match_parent. When I want to set the imageview bitmap I use the height and the width of the imageView to load the best size bitmap. The issue is the imageView size is sometime not known in the Loader bindView (not measured yet?). How could I get the width of bitmap every time in this case ?

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ....
        bitmap = BitmapHelper.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile( new File(file), iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to provide dimensions to create the bitmap ? You could just use the original bitmap and set the appropriate scaleType on your ImageView, right ?

Comment: I have large images and I want to load small bitmaps in the memory to avoid OOM. [Android training - Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the view is initialised, then get the dimensions. Try using a ViewObserver like so:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = YOURLAYOUT.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
   viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
             YOURLAYOUT.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
             //do some things
             //YOURLAYOUT.getWidth() should give a correct answer
          }
   });
}
```

Hope that helps :)